# How to plot bullet chart using python-nvd3?

Tags: django, d3.js, bower, nvd3.js, python-nvd3

I am completely new to python web development and this is my first web app using Python and Django. For plotting purposes I am using python-nvd3. I followed the instructions here : http://python-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#documentation

In python-nvd3 has lots of chart types like Barchart,Line Chart and pie chart etc..In my project i need to plot a Bullet Chart but i didn't get.I have no idea to plot bullet chart using python-nvd3.

If anyone have idea to plot bullet chart using python-nvd3 kindly share with me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to plot **Bullet chart** in python NVD3 because its just a wrapper for D3 charts . instead of python nvd3 you can use nvd3.js then you can plot bullet chart . follow this link `http://nvd3.org/examples/bullet.html`

Comment: Thank you for your response, i found this is useful